# pandas multi-index dataframe - data inserted to new column and sub-row only visible in column view?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, multi-index

I am trying to insert a list of data into a multi-level pandas dataframe.
It seems to work just fine, but when I view the entire dataframe, the new sub-row is not there.
Here is an example:

Create an empty multi-index dataframe:

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], ['a', 'b','c']]) #set up index 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'], index=ind)                    #create empty df with multi-level nested index
print(df)
```

```
    col1
A a  NaN
  b  NaN
  c  NaN
B a  NaN
  b  NaN
  c  NaN
C a  NaN
  b  NaN
  c  NaN
```

Inserting a new column works fine:

```
newcol = 'col2'      #new column name
df[newcol] = np.nan  #fill new column with nans
print(df)
```

```
    col1  col2
A a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
B a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
C a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
```

Inserting data into an existing sub-row works with point data but not with a list:

```
df[newcol]['A','a'] = 1        #works with point data but not with list
print(df)
```

```
    col1  col2
A a  NaN   1.0
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
B a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
C a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
```

Inserting into new sub-row looks OK when viewing just the one column:

```
df[newcol]['A','d'] = [1,2,3]  #insert into new sub-row 'd'
print(df[newcol])              #view just new column
```

```
A  a            1
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
B  a          NaN
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
C  a          NaN
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
A  d    [1, 2, 3]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

But it's not visible when viewing the entire dataframe - why?

```
print(df)
```

```
    col1  col2
A a  NaN   1.0
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
B a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
C a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
```

Also, when I try different methods of inserting the data, I run into issues:
Using df.loc[] works perfectly for a single data point, but not for lists:

```
df.loc[('A','f'),  newcol] = 1          #create new row at [(row,sub-row),column] & insert point data
print(df)                               #works fine
```

```
    col1  col2
A a  NaN   1.0
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
B a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
C a  NaN   NaN
  b  NaN   NaN
  c  NaN   NaN
A f  NaN   1.0
```

Same method but inserting a list returns an error:

```
df.loc[('A','f'),  newcol] = [1,2,3]    #create new row at [(row,sub-row),column] & insert list data
```

`TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()`

Using df.at[] returns error with both point and list data:

`data.at[('A','f'), newcol] = [1,2,3]    #insert into existing sub-row 'f'`

`KeyError: ('A', 'f')`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `df[newcol]['A','d'] = [1,2,3]`, it is chained-indexing assignment, so the result is unpredictable. Pandas doesn't guarantee correct behaviors when you do chained-indexing. When you run that command, pandas executes with a warning. This warning even includes the link to the full explanation in case you want to know. I don't go into the detail because the link in the warning explains very well on this chained-indexing.

On assigning list to a cell, it is always a pain. However, it is doable. I guess your issue with `df.loc[('A','f'),  newcol] = [1,2,3]` because `col2` is dtype `float`, so pandas doesn't consider `[1,2,3]` as a single object `list`. It considers `[1,2,3]` as a list of multiple numeric values, so it failed. I don't know whether it is a bug or intentional.

To solve your issue with `.loc`, convert `col2` to dtype `object` and do assignment

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('O')
df.loc[('A','f'),  'col2'] = [1,2,3]

print(df)

Out[1911]:
    col1       col2
A a  NaN        NaN
  b  NaN        NaN
  c  NaN        NaN
B a  NaN        NaN
  b  NaN        NaN
  c  NaN        NaN
C a  NaN        NaN
  b  NaN        NaN
  c  NaN        NaN
A f  NaN  [1, 2, 3]

print(df['col2'])

Out[1912]:
A  a          NaN
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
B  a          NaN
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
C  a          NaN
   b          NaN
   c          NaN
A  f    [1, 2, 3]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```